# JAXB annotation for childnode attribute

Tags: xml, jaxb, annotations, xmlnode

Lets say that i have following XML and i use JAXB for marshalling:

```
<bookstore name="bookstoreName">
    <book title="bookTitle">
         <author fullname="authorName">
         </author>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

I know how to create:

- root node
- attributes of root node
- child nodes

I did this by using annotations @XmlRootElement, @XmlElement and @XmlAttribute.

What i don't know is how to create attributes of child nodes. For example attribute "title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` will be a property on the `Book` class annotated with `@XmlAttribute`.  `Book` will be referenced by `BookStore` probably as a `List` property.

```java
@XmlElement(name="book")
List<Book> getBooks() {
    return books;
}
```

Comment: So basically i should have 2 classes. One for *Bookstore* and second one for *Book*? In class *Book* i will have *@XmlAttribute* *title* and *@XmlElement* *author*. 
And in class Bookstore I will have *@XmlAttribute* *name* and *@XmlElement* of class type *Book*?

Comment: @exemplum - Exactly, I have updated my answer with what the `books` property on `Bookstore` could look like.